# Troubleshoot CUDA on Linux for GeForce GT 730

Tags: linux, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, cuda

I'm setting up CUDA toolkit on Linux for a GT730 graphic card. When running deviceQuery it always gets an error `cudaGetDeviceCount returned 38 ... no CUDA-capable device is detected.

Has anybody successfully run CUDA on GT730? What's driver version, and toolkit version you use? How do you troubleshoot or debug this problem?

The driver and toolkit versions that have been tried are: driver 331.89 which has newly added support for GT730, and driver 340.24 which supports GT730, toolkit 5.5.22 and 6.0.37.

While I do see a similar question about 9500 GT. Tough checking supported devices on Nvidia site it does not list GT730 but lists GT730M twice. Since I do know GT730 has CUDA, maybe GT730 is too new to be supported in release toolkit, or the Nvidia site is not up to date yet? Do you have previous experience with newer cards?

Any suggestions and other hints?

Note: I'm migrating this question from stackoverflow as they suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the 331.89 or 340.24 from `xorg-edgers` ppa does not work with cuda. downloaded toolkit 6.5 rc with driver 340.21. Here is the tricks:

- [1] Install nvidia-331 of 331.89. Also nvidia-settings-331. Both are from `xorg-edgers` ppa.
- [2] Install driver from toolkit 6.5 rc. But does not let it configure x. The step [1] is to allow this step to stop x by `service mdm stop`. Without [1], if you stop x the terminal will be unusable.
- [3] Open the module alias files under `/lib/...` which can be found by following the symbol link from `/etc/modprobe.d/...` for nvidia 331 driver. Edit to comment out the nvidia_331 and nvidia_uvm_331 alias. Thus the 331.21 driver `nvidia.ko` and `nvidia-uvm.ko` can be loaded at boot time. Without changing this the file loaded are some from 331.89.